# Statistics - relationship between margin of error and error rate

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to validate an algorithm I wrote against a bunch of data I gathered and I'm not sure if I'm understanding how to validate the error rate against the margin of error.

I calculated a sample size from a population using a margin of error of 5%.  I'm getting the sample size like this:

```
   /// Calculates the required sample size assuming an infinite population
    /// 
    ///      Z^2 * (p) * (1-p)
    /// SS = -----------------
    ///             C^2
    ///             
    /// SS = sample size
    /// Z = z-score  (based on confidence level e.g. 95%, std dev 1)
    /// p = odds for a patient to have a match (51.8)
    /// c = confidence interval, margin of error  (5%)
    /// 
    /// 
    /// 
    /// Then correct for finite population
    /// 
    ///                     ss
    /// Adjusted SS = ---------------
    ///                     ss - 1
    ///                 1+  --------
    ///                       pop
    ///                       
    /// pop = total population
    /// ss = sample size for infinite population
    ///
```

Then I took a population and calculated the actual rate of occurrence from the entire population, which is `51.8%`.

Then I ran the sample 323 times and calculated the error rate for each run like this:

`((Actual rate – estimated rate)/Actual rate) * 100 = error rate %`

What I expected was that the error rate % would be within the margin of error (5%) 307 times out of the 323 runs (95% confidence).  However, what I actually saw was that it was within the margin of error 251 times (77.7%).

Am I using the error rate correctly?  Can you use the error rate as a measure of the margin of error like that?

Comment: What would happen if instead you considered `(Actual rate – estimated rate) * 100 = error rate %` ?

Comment: well, then I don't get a percentage at all.

Comment: You get the difference between two rates - perhaps that is what is regarded as the error (measured as a percentage since it is multiplied by $100$).  In your formulation your formula would need take into account the factor of $49$ difference to the error percentage between an actual population rate of $98\%$ and an actual population rate of $2\%$, and it clearly does not

Comment: thanks, I've determined that my understanding of the relationship between margin of error and error rate wasn't correct. I was making some incorrect assumptions.